# How do I center a fixed marquee?

Tags: html, css

So Basically I have created a marquee and I want the marquee to be fixed. I have managed to do this but it isn't centered. I have tried margin-left:auto; & margin-right:auto; in the CSS file but no luck.  doesn't seem to work either...

Code:

```
#fixedmarq {
position:fixed;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right: auto;

 }
```

HTML Code:

```
 <div id="fixedmarq"><marquee width="500" bgcolor="#000000"><span style="font-weight: 400; font-family: changa-    one; font-style: normal; font-size:24px; color:#FFFFFF">Welcome back to the NEW CanteraFC website! We hope you like it!</marquee></div>
```

Comment: `marquee` tag is a nice remembrance on '92. but I'm sorry to tell you that now (2014) is long time a deprecated tag.

Comment: If you're still using marquee take a look at this website for reference http://www2.warnerbros.com/spacejam/movie/jam.htm ;)

Comment: Yeah the theme I am going for is old school so marquee fits in there quite nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure about a depreciated element such as marquee since I haven't worked with it, but I'll assume it works like any other element.

If you are making the marquee fixed, `margin: 0 auto` will not work, as `auto` margins don't play well with fixed elements.

However, you can have a quick fix by making an parent div to the marquee have a width of `100%` and specify `margin: 0 auto;` to the marquee inside the div element.  You'll also need to make sure you assign the property `display: block`, as `auto` margins do not work on inline elements.

[Take a look at this jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/hc6LL/1/)